# Unable to show extreme values on guide_colourbar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am unable to show the extreme values on a colourbar, even when using the `draw.ulim` option (defauls to true anyway).

Does anyone have a idea how to solve this, apart from manually lowering the extreme values (this works, but I don't like doing so)?

It's not the result of the large height setting that I used.

```
fam_labels = structure(list(Group.1 = c(2, -1.4), x = c("Ecuador", "Sweden"
)), .Names = c("Group.1", "x"), row.names = c("2", "21"), class = "data.frame")
fam_limits = c(-1.4, 2)
spag_plot_data = structure(list(intercept = c(49.649, 47.65), fam_slope = c(0.59744125, 
0.50000099), country = c("Sweden", "Ecuador"), Gender = structure(c(2L, 
1L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"), FACFAM = c(-1.42225, 
1.99999)), .Names = c("intercept", "fam_slope", "country", "Gender", 
"FACFAM"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(57L, 84L))

(spaghetti = ggplot(data = spag_plot_data) + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 2.4,y = intercept, yend = intercept + fam_slope * 2.4, 
         group = country, linetype = Gender, colour = FACFAM), show_guide = T) + 
    scale_x_continuous("Age", breaks = seq(0,24,by=5)/10, labels = seq(16,40,by=5), 
         limits = c(0, 2.4)) + 
    scale_colour_continuous("Onset of family role responsibilites (blue = early)", 
         guide = guide_colourbar(barheight=40,draw.ulim = T,
         draw.llim = T),high = "#89CFF0", low = "pink", space = "Lab", 
         breaks= fam_labels[,1],labels=fam_labels[,2], limits = fam_limits)
)
```

(This reproducible snippet is of course only a subset of the data).

Comment: It is controllable by something like `limits=sort(fam_labels[,1])`. However, `FACFAM` for Sweden is -1.42, which is less than -1.4 from `fam_labels`, so it won't be seen.

Comment: @tonytonov Good catch, I had assumed that the limits are set based on the breaks not based on the data. These differed because I had rounded FACFAM because I was grouping countries in the legend, so sometimes the breaks exceeded the data-given limits. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept, or maybe this question should be deleted because it's very localised.

Comment: I decided to post since there's a related bug I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`limits` are controlling the lower and the upper limit for the scale, while `breaks` and `labels` indicate which values are marked with ticks.

There is one interesting issue I found when experimenting with your data. You have to be sure that for `limits=c(lower, upper)` holds `lower<upper`. Otherwise, R may crash (if colour scale is used, for x and y just nothing will be plotted). Created a bug report in the [Github repo](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/906).